# Where am i going wrong with using typescript and redux to retrieve the stores data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

This is my reducer -----

```
import {
  WorkoutList,
  STARTED_WORKOUT,
  END_WORKOUT,
  WorkoutActionTypes,
} from "../types";

export const initialState: WorkoutList = {
  workouts: [
    {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      name: "Leg Day",
      date: new Date(),
      duration: 60,
      started: false,
      completed: false,
      exerises: [
        {
          id: Math.random().toString(),
          name: "Squats",
          completed: false,
          sets: [
            {
              id: Math.random().toString(),
              reps: 12,
              weight: 60,
              completed: false,
            },
            {
              id: Math.random().toString(),
              reps: 12,
              weight: 60,
              completed: false,
            },
            {
              id: Math.random().toString(),
              reps: 12,
              weight: 60,
              completed: false,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const workoutListReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: WorkoutActionTypes
): WorkoutList => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STARTED_WORKOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        workouts: state.workouts.map((workout) =>
          workout.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...workout, started: true }
            : workout
        ),
      };

    case END_WORKOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        workouts: state.workouts.map((workout) =>
          workout.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...workout, completed: true }
            : workout
        ),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default workoutListReducer;
```

This is the root reducer-----

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import workoutListReducer from "./workoutlist";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  workoutList: workoutListReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

This is where I am trying to retrieve the stores information in my component------

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { WorkoutList as workouts, Workout } from "../types";

// interface Props {}

interface StateProps {
  workoutlist: workouts;
}

const WorkoutList: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonMenuButton />
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>Your Workout</IonTitle>
            <IonButtons slot="end">
              <IonButton>
                <IonIcon icon={personCircleOutline} slot="icon-only" />
              </IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
          <IonGrid>
            {console.log(props)} // This is where I am console logging it.
          </IonGrid>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateProps) => ({
  workoutlist: state.workoutlist,
});

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string;
};

export default connector(WorkoutList);
```

I have tried using useSelector and as you can see trying to use connect. I am just a little lost in general though using typescript with redux. All I want to do at the moment is access the workouts in the initialState to console.log them in my component. As of now, when I console.log(props), it shows workoutlist as undefined.

I am fairly confident I did the actions and action types correctly.

If anyone has any advice or needs more information please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have anything named as Props in your component. Instead you should derive your props from StateProps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mapStateToProps` and `interface` `workoutlist` should be `workoutList` **(capital L)**

```js
...
interface StateProps {
  workoutList: workouts;
}
...
const mapStateToProps = (state: StateProps) => ({
  workoutlist: state.workoutList, //<----here
});
...
```